# How to retrive list item return value in button click?

Tags: c#

I have a function like

```
 public static List<DateTime> GetDates(int year, int month)
{
    var dates = new List<DateTime>();
    for (var date = new DateTime(year, month, 1); date.Month == month; date = date.AddDays(1))
    {
        dates.Add(date);
    }
    return dates;
}
public void GetDates()
{
    int year =Convert.ToInt32( ddyear.SelectedItem.Value);
    int month =Convert.ToInt32( ddmonth.SelectedItem.Value);
}
```

Now I want the return `dates` result in my Submit buttin click..how can I do it??

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetDates();
}
```

Comment: Call the first `GetDates` method and get the return value. What is the problem with that?

Comment: return to who ? You want those dates shown somewhere ?

Comment: @Philip Stuyck,The retus dates value I want to acces within my Submit_Click function

Comment: var dates = GetDates() what is the problem with that ?

Comment: @ Philip Stuyck,Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

Answer (score 0):

Decide your self if you want to return the data or you want to print the data from getdates() method. 
If you want to return the data, 
Change void to a tuple class return type or use the ref parameters to hold the return value.
If you want to print the data,
Wrote the print functionality in get dates() method.